Using Java Process to run MacOS SQLite Query
I'm trying to use Java's Process class to run a query on the MacOS Photos database (given the UUID, what's the original HEIC filename?). I'm able to load the database and run the query successfully from the Terminal command line. But when I start the Process, I'm unable to collect the responses from its BufferedInputReader.
Here's the code I'm executing:
String uuid = "\"838C3AD6-D5E8-4340-8DD5-0EB8244D\"";
SqliteProcess sp = new SqliteProcess(10000, uuid);
sp.start();
try {
   sp.join(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}
System.out.println("UUID: " + uuid + ", Filename: " + sp.filename);

And here's the class:
public class SqliteProcess extends Thread {

    private Process proc = null;
    private long timeout;
    private String uuid;
    public String filename = "";

    public SqliteProcess(long timeout, String uuid) {
        super();
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlite3", "/Users/ferdberfle/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/Photos.sqlite"); // or whatever your command is
        try {
            proc = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        String s = commandAndResponse("SELECT ZMASTER FROM ZASSET WHERE ZUUID = \"" + uuid + "\";");
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + s);
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            sqlEnd();
            return;
        }
        filename = commandAndResponse("SELECT ZORIGINALFILENAME FROM ZCLOUDMASTER WHERE Z_PK = \"" + s + "\";");
        System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + filename);
        sqlEnd();
    }

    private void sqlEnd() {
        try {
            BufferedWriter bw = proc.outputWriter();
            bw.write(".exit");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    private String commandAndResponse(String c) {
        if (!c.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter bw = proc.outputWriter();
                bw.write(c);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        String buff = "";
        BufferedReader br = proc.inputReader();
        String line;                     // This is where the code freezes. No exception,
        try {                            // but it never comes back from br.readLine().
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                buff += line;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        return buff;
    }

Anybody able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

first problem: ignoring exceptions, or its message ( like in catch (IOException ex) {} or catch (IOException ex) { return ""; } )

Always (at least at first) use the pattern ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sqlite3", "/Users/ferdberfle/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/Photos.sqlite").inheritIO(); and let it run. It will be read for you

You've missed out so much information which would explain. What does the error stream show, what is exit code, does the process end or are you just getting the (missing) result as the join(N) times out? Why not use JDBC?

DuncG I prefer not to use JDBC because it means adding a library to my project and complicating distribution/installation. I've tried pulling the error stream and yes, it warns me if I have the SQL syntax wrong. But I'm not getting help with starting up a Process then interacting with the command-line application.

But I'm not getting help with starting up a Process then interacting with the command-line application You are. Let me make it even easier for you than I did already: new ProcessBuilder("sqlite3", "/Users/ferdberfle/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/Photos.sqlite").inheritIO().start();

Sorry, g00se, I meant the error stream didn't give me help. And I tried inheritIO() but it still stalled when waiting for an answer to the Sqlite SELECT command.

It certainly shouldn't have behaved any differently to how it would issuing the command directly

I managed to do this by abandoning the idea of interacting with the running process and instead calling a Sqlite process with an INNER JOIN command.
String s = app.filenameFromUUID("838C3AD6-D5E8-4340-8CC5-0EB8244D8890");
System.out.println("ANSWER: " + s);

public String filenameFromUUID(String uuid) {
        long timeout = 10000L;
        String fname = "file:///" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/database/Photos.sqlite?mode=ro";
        SqliteProcess p1 = new SqliteProcess(timeout, "sqlite3", fname,
                "SELECT ZORIGINALFILENAME FROM ZCLOUDMASTER zcm INNER JOIN ZASSET za ON zcm.Z_PK = za.ZMASTER WHERE za.ZUUID = \'" + uuid + "\';");
        p1.startAndWait();
        return p1.answer;
}

public class SqliteProcess extends Thread {

    private final String command[];
    private Process proc;
    private final long timeout;

    public int exitCode = 0;
    public boolean completed = false;
    public boolean exception = false;
    public boolean timed_out = false;
    public String answer = "";
    public String errMsg = "";

    private InputStream is;

    public SqliteProcess(long timeout, String... args) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
        command = new String[args.length];
        System.arraycopy(args, 0, command, 0, command.length);
    }
    
    public SqliteProcess startAndWait() {
        start();
        try {
            join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        return this;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();      // Shell command with "/c" to terminate immediately
        builder.command(command);
        builder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        try {
            proc = builder.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            errMsg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            int pos = errMsg.indexOf("Error message: ");
            if (pos >= 0) {
                errMsg = errMsg.substring(pos + 15);
            }
            exception = true;
            return;
        }
        is = proc.getInputStream();
        try {
            proc.waitFor(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            errMsg = "Command interrupted ";
            exception = true;
            return;
        }
        completed = !proc.isAlive();
        if (!completed) {
            errMsg = "Command timeout";
            timed_out = true;
        }
        if (is != null) {
            answer = getReply(proc);
        }
        exitCode = proc.exitValue();
    }

    private static String getReply(Process proc) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream input = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        try {
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                input.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return "";
        }
        return input.toString().trim();
    }

}


Not sure why you're doing that. It's a simple JOIN query

Sigh. I've clearly betrayed my ignorance of Sqlite! Are you suggesting a single command would accomplish this?

Yes. You probably want something like SELECT ZORIGINALFILENAME FROM ZCLOUDMASTER zcm INNER JOIN ZASSET za ON zcm.Z_PK = za.ZMASTER WHERE za.ZUUID = ? Try it at the command line first, having supplied a value where that placeholder is

Simplify: public static String getReply(Process proc) throws IOException {ByteArrayOutputStream input = new ByteArrayOutputStream();proc.getInputStream().transferTo(input);return input.toString();}
